# NServiceBus Upgrade SendOnly

Tags: transactions, upgrade, nservicebus

Upgrading my NServiceBus from 3.2.8 to 4.6.1:

I have an EndPoint.cs that looked like this:

```
using System;
using NServiceBus;

namespace GripMonitor
{
    public class EndPointConfig : IWantCustomInitialization, IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Client 
    {
        public void Init()
        {
            SetLoggingLibrary.Log4Net(log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure);

            Configure.With(AllAssemblies.Except("Oracle.DataAccess.dll"))
                .DefaultBuilder()
                .XmlSerializer()
                .MsmqTransport().TransactionTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
                .IsTransactional(true)
                .UnicastBus()
                .DoNotCreateQueues()
                .SendOnly();
        }
    }
}
```

and now looks like this:

```
using System;
using NServiceBus;

namespace GripMonitor
{
    public class EndPointConfig : IWantCustomInitialization, IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Client
    {
        public void Init()
        {
            SetLoggingLibrary.Log4Net(() => log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure());

            Configure.Transactions.Enable().Advanced( s=> s.DefaultTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)));
            Configure.Serialization.Xml();

            Configure.With(AllAssemblies.Except("Oracle.DataAccess.dll"))
                .DefaultBuilder()
                .UseTransport<Msmq>()
                .UnicastBus()
                .DoNotCreateQueues()
                .SendOnly();;

        }
    }
}
```

I get the following unhandled exception and the application crashes:

Unable to set the value for key: Transactions.Enabled. The settings has been locked for modifications. Please move any configuration code earlier in the configuration pipeline.

Deleting the last line: //.SendOnly(); fixes the problem.

Why is this?

Thanks,
Miguel

Edit1: Changed the title

Answer (score 0):

It's a little odd to have an NServiceBus.Host endpoint that is completely send-only, but it is possible. Based on the name of the namespace I see in your code, I take it you're just monitoring something and sending messages with that monitored thing's status, so that does make sense.

However, the `.SendOnly()` extension method is really meant to be used as a shortcut when self-hosting, because it finalizes the configuration and immediately returns the IBus instance.

Here's the actual (reflected) code for `.SendOnly()`:

```
public static IBus SendOnly(this Configure config)
{
  Configure.Endpoint.AsSendOnly();
  config.Initialize();
  return config.Builder.Build<IBus>();
}
```

So the problem is that an the `Init()` method of an `EndpointConfig` implementing `IWantCustomInitialization` runs very first in the Host's startup process (much more information on that in my blog post [NServiceBus and the Mystery of IWantCustomInitialization](http://www.make-awesome.com/2014/05/nservicebus-and-the-mystery-of-iwantcustominitialization/)) and at that point, the endpoint isn't even ***close*** to being done. The default things that an NServiceBus.Host endpoint will try to do during startup are going to attempt to modify the same settings that have been locked and finalized in order to return the `IBus` instance.

I would think you could get by without the call to `.SendOnly()`, or perhaps just insert `Configure.Endpoint.AsSendOnly();` before the `Configure.With()...` block.